# Query returns cartesian product when not expected

Tags: sql, oracle, join

**Task:** Select all orders having products belonging to `‘Sea Food’` category.

**Result:** OrderNo, OrderDate, Product Name

I write this query but it returns Cartesian products.

```
select  o.orderid, o.orderdate as "Order Date", p.productname , ct.categoryname from orders o, 
order_details od , products p , customers c ,categories ct  
where 
od.orderid = o.orderid and p.productid = od.productid and  ct.categoryid = p.categoryid 
and ct.categoryname = 'Seafood';
```

**Question:** What is wrong with my query ?

Comment: For one, it is using archive syntax where commas are over-used in the `FROM` clause.  Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Please use `join` instead of `where` to join tables. The internal working for the two is very different. If you use a where clause to join your table, Oracle first does a Cartesian product of all the tables and then applies the where clauses, which is why you are getting a Cartesian product.

Comment: the customer table is not being used in the where clause?

Comment: @Munir nice explanation that's why some time it returns correct result and sometime return Cartesian product

Comment: @cableload accepted answer removing customer table resolve the error

Comment: @Munir I'll agree with your first sentence, but the rest of your comment about the old Oracle syntax always doing a Cartesian product when joining via a where clause is complete nonsense.

Comment: @KrisJohnston My comment is from my experience, which may not be as much as yours. I see a difference in the way queries work when using `where` vs `join` in the plan tables. Maybe it's not always true, but it's definitely not nonsense.

Comment: @Munir When asked about any performance difference between the old Oracle join syntax and ANSI join syntax, Tom Kyte said: "nope, it is the same (or should be...)" in this link (search on "performance"): https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6585774577187 Oracle only started supporting ANSI join syntax starting in 9i... Oracle would have been a completely useless DBMS pre 9i if the Oracle join syntax worked like you described...

Comment: @KrisJohnston Like I said, my experience says that the plans can be different for the two syntax. I have only used Oracle 11g and it is maintained by my company's DBA, so I do not know if there are settings that are doing that. I cannot comment on older versions of Oracle since I have not used those. Also, this discussion isn't adding anything constructive to this question since we both agree the `join` syntax should be used here. So, I don't see the point of continuing it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a `CROSS JOIN` on `customers` table since you forgot to specify the connection. This is why you should use explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than old syntax using commas in `WHERE` clause.

After translating your query into explicit syntax, you will see that there is no `WHERE` condition involving `customers` table:

```
select  
 o.orderid, 
 o.orderdate as "Order Date", 
 p.productname, 
 ct.categoryname 
from 
 orders o, 
 inner join order_details od on od.orderid = o.orderid
 inner join products p on p.productid = od.productid
 inner join categories ct on ct.categoryid = p.categoryid
 cross join customers c -- either you don't need this table, or you need to specify conditions
where 
 ct.categoryname = 'Seafood'
```

Basically the reason you got it was that your where clause omitted join condition involving `customers` table, so you were left with:

```
from (...), customers -- cross join when joining condition not applied in where clause
```

Comment: Yes after removing customer table from my query it returns correct result